# Inserting into a text file using tcl

Tags: file, unix, tcl

My tcl script is designed to update a table in CSV file inserting a new row under its header.
Let's say there are only 2 columns: "Date" and "Description".
To do that, I first open the CSV file in a **read mode**, store its whole content as a variable and close that file.
Then I open the file again in a **write mode** and overwrite its content by my variable (which I update according my requirements).
The simplified code is:

```
proc updateCSV {myDescription myDate myPath} {
    set newContent "Date,Description\n$myDate,$myDescription";

    #Stage A: Process the target file in a read mode:
    set targetFile [open $myPath "r"];
    #Store the existing content and remove the first line (header-line)
    set existingContent [read $targetFile];
    set newlinePos [string first "\n" $existingContent];
    set oldContent [string range $existingContent $newlinePos+1 end];
    close $targetFile;

    #Stage B: Process the target file in a write mode:
    set targetFile [open $myPath "w"];
    #Add the header-line and the new content-line, overwrite the whole existing content:
    puts $targetFile $newContent;   
    #Append the previous content:
    seek $targetFile 0 end;
    puts -nonewline $targetFile $oldContent;
    close $targetFile;
}
```

What bothers me is that the above solution seems too clumsy.
Is there a way to do the same stuff by:
a) processing the target file only once;
b) avoid overwriting its content but rather updating it directly?

Comment: "Don't sweat the small stuff" - you have a simple solution that works.  There's no real need to optimise it unless you start seeing real problems, e.g. if the file gets to be gigabytes in size then rewriting it might be noticeably slow.  Otherwise I would advise not to overcomplicate things.

Comment: FYI, On Unix like systems you can't "insert" more characters in a file without rewriting the entire file. You can only append characters to a file without having to rewrite it. I say "Unix like systems" because I've used plenty of other operating systems where files are not simply a sequence of bytes and it is possible to insert a new line (typically called a "record")  without having to rewrite the entire file. You are unlikely to ever encounter such an operating system.

Comment: If you're really into inserting data, it might be easier to switch to using a database table, perhaps via SQLite.

Comment: Indeed, this is not a big file so I don't have issues with performance (nor is it worth creating a database). I just felt that I miss something and that the solution is not intuitive. Thank you for the explanation, that was helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than reading the entire file, modifying it, and then overwriting the content, you can use a different approach that involves reading the file line by line, making modifications as needed, and then writing those changes to a new file. Here's an example using Tcl to update the CSV file directly without overwriting its content:

```
proc updateCSV {myDescription myDate myPath} {
    set tempFile [file tempfile updatedCSV];
    set header "Date,Description";

    # Open the input file for reading
    set inputFile [open $myPath "r"];
    set outputFile [open $tempFile "w"];

    # Read and write the header to the output file
    puts $outputFile $header;

    # Flag to indicate whether the header was found
    set headerFound 0;

    # Process each line of the input file
    while {[gets $inputFile line] != -1} {
        if {!$headerFound && [string equal $line $header]} {
            # Skip the existing header in the input file
            set headerFound 1;
            continue;
        }
        # Write the line to the output file
        puts $outputFile $line;
    }

    # Append the new row to the end of the file
    puts $outputFile "$myDate,$myDescription";

    # Close both files
    close $inputFile;
    close $outputFile;

    # Replace the original file with the updated file
    file rename -force $tempFile $myPath;
}
```

This script reads the input CSV file line by line. It skips the existing header and writes all other lines to a temporary file (updatedCSV). After processing all lines, it appends the new row ($myDate,$myDescription) to the end of the file and then replaces the original file with the updated one.

This way, you're not required to store the entire content in a variable, and it operates more efficiently by directly modifying the file as needed without overwriting its content entirely.